# variable doesn't count up even though the function is called over and over

Tags: c++, function, variables

I want the variable "minne" to be counted upwards once ever time I run the function "multi" and then print it back on the screen in the main function. 
This doesnt happen though, it is stuck on telling me I used the function "0" times over and over again. Why is that?

```
//Multi

#include <iostream>


//Deklarerar variablar
int a,b,x, minne;

//Deklarerar funktioner
int multi(int a, int b);

int main(void)
{
  using std::cout;
  using std::cin; 

  while(1 < 2)
  {
  cout << "Ge mig ett nummer som du vill multiplicera:\n"; 
  cin >> a;
  cout << "\n Och ett till tack: \n";
  cin >> b;

  multi(a,b);

  cout << "\n Summan av dessa tal är: " << x << "\n";
  cout << "You have called the function: " << minne << " times.\n";
  }

  return 0;
}

int multi(int a, int b)
{
  x = a * b;

  int minne = minne + 1;

  return x, minne;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't your compiler warn about this? `int minne = minne + 1` "uses" an uninitialised variable (yes, the local one!). Fix your build settings!

Comment: And I'm not quite sure what `while (1 < 2)` or `return x, minne` are supposed to achieve..

Comment: You should turn on compiler warnings to maximum settings and invest in a debugger.  StackOverflow is a very slow process for debugging code.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I'd give him credit for coming up with `while (1 <2)` for being an infinite loop. Not sure what the first one i wrote looked like.  @Adrian  while(true) or while(1) works just as well and are more traditional. Optimized away regardless but not as shocking to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hiding the global `minne` with your local `int minne` - get rid of the `int` and just write `minne = minne + 1`, or even just `++minne`. Also, you don't need to return anything from the function as you're not using the result.

Comment: Looks like it shouldn't return anything at all.

Comment: @Adrian: It's returning `minne`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have a global **minne** declared and the function multi also declares a local **minne** which hides the global **minne**

Answer (score 1):

1. You can return only one variable from a function.
2. Variable `minne` in `main()` is 0 becouse it's scope is global and it was automaticly initialized with 0. `minne` in `multi()` function is local and is "created" every time You call that function (destroyed on function exit).

What you want to do is:

```
//Multi

#include <iostream>


//Deklarerar variablar
int a,b,x;
static int minne;

//Deklarerar funktioner
int multi(int a, int b);

int main(void)
{
  using std::cout;
  using std::cin; 

  while(1 < 2)
  {
  cout << "Ge mig ett nummer som du vill multiplicera:\n"; 
  cin >> a;
  cout << "\n Och ett till tack: \n";
  cin >> b;

  multi(a,b);

  cout << "\n Summan av dessa tal är: " << x << "\n";
  cout << "You have called the function: " << minne << " times.\n";
  }

  return 0;
}

int multi(int a, int b)
{
  x = a * b;

  minne = minne + 1;

  return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're redefining it.

Instead of

```
int minne = minne + 1;
```

Do

```
minne = minne + 1;
```

Creating local variable with the same name as the global one shadows the global one.

Also, what's the point of your return statement? What are you trying to do by doing `return x, minne;`? And you don't even check the return value at all...

Comment: x returns the sum of a and b multiplied by each other.

Comment: @AdrianLarsson your function doesn't return `x`, it returns `minne`. I'm sure that's not what you intended. You're using the operator `,` in a way you shouldn't be.

Comment: How come it actually gave me the answer to the math problem then?

Comment: Because `x` is a global variable and you discard the function return value. That's why you were told that the function shouldn't return anything at all. What I'm trying to understand is what do you **think** that the statement `return x,minne` does.

Comment: @Adrian: Because you're not using the result of the function, you're using the global `x` which does contain the right result.

Comment: I thought I was sending back the x and minne packed with the data I "produced" in multi.

Comment: @AdrianLarsson you're not "sending" back anything. Function returns a value, and it can only return one value, not two. You need to read again about what functions are and how they work in C/C++. In this particular case, because you're using global variables, you don't need to return anything at all and your function should be of type `void` (bad practice, but that's what you're doing right now). In general, using global values is a bad idea, and when you don't use global values, you should return the result of your calculation through reference parameters or with the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Because minne inside multi is not the one outside of it. You redeclared it as a variable local to multi, it's that one that gets incremented and then lost when you return

Comment: Not actually necessary - the `minne` he's trying to increment is a global.

Comment: I know that you know that, they know that. The compiler did as it was told though....